# SSRS Reporting Service connections and credentials

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer

We are currently using Reporting Services 2010 with SSRS reports in our application. When a report is opened, there are 10-15 db connections made and then when the report viewer is closed all the connections never close. You can easily accumulate over 100 open db connections from the reports by just opening a few reports.

Does anyone have any experience with this as best approach to handle this and what causes this? There seems to be very little that shows up in Google search regarding excessive db connections.

Thanks in advance for any advice or links to look at.

Update: It appears that the report viewer is trying 7-8 times to get network credentials and we have those stored in the database. So I guess the real question is why does the report viewer attempt to get network credentials that many times for one report and can this be restricted?

Comment: SSRS is part of SQL Server and there is no SQL Server 2010 but there is a version of the BI development tools for Visual Studio 2010. My guess is you're using SQL Server & SSRS 2012. Also, I'm really unclear as to what the problem is. You have network credentials (for what?) stored in the database? Do you mean you have the data source authentication stored in the shared data source? I can't say I've noticed that SSRS leaves the DB connections open for a long time. Is this part of some custom code you've written or is it the native SSRS data source connections?

Comment: Hello Mike - I put the Report Viewer connection back in the config files. I have a Report Viewer in an aspx page. The main issue that I am not understanding is that for each report you pull up in report viewer, the Report Viewer goes to get URL and Credentials around 7 times. I am confused at why Report Viewer would need to get the connection info and credentials more than one time a report. Is there any way to limit this or force Report Viewer to use existing connection?